# Bluetooth Security Concern

Tags: security, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are developing sensors which will be distributed in large quantities and broadcast BLE every 5s in order to have access to DFU and Data Sending. The DFU is encrypted from the manufacturer's end however the Data Sending (NUS/UART) is left open and so we are looking for ways to encrypt the data or limit access to this service from unwanted users. A static PIN key could be used however since it is only 4 digits long (usually), there are only 10,000 combinations. It would be appreciated if you could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bluetooth standard won't help you solve this in a good way. Its pairing / bonding features are designed to prevent remote attacks while a user is pairing with the device, not to prevent any person from pairing at all. You should see the question as a general question and not a Bluetooth-specific one in my opinion.

Unless you want to pre-bond all the sensors to some legit device and then prevent new pairings (which would of course solve your problem, but might be cumbersome in practice), you should use something else than what the Bluetooth standards offers.

For example, if you are happy with having a password to access the sensors, you can implement a PAKE scheme (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) and then encrypt and sign all data using the derived key. You can also simply use TLS, or some other certificate-based solution.

If you are lazy and think it's too hard to implement proper cryptography you can otherwise just have a characteristic that the user writes a password to, and if it's accepted, the data sending service opens up. This of course is unsecure because an attacker can sniff the connection and find the password. The same applies when you have a static PIN and use standard Bluetooth pairing.